# How to deal with array size issue

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I have a matrix of size 84*173628. I have to perform following kind of multiplication

L = R' * P *  R

Where size of R is 84*173628, size of P is 84*84. The error message says 'Requested 173628x173628 (112.3GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference.'

Any suggestions please!

Comment: All the rows of the matrix have non zero data? You could try with sparse matrix.

Comment: @AlessandroTrigilio, All the rows are nonzero otherwise I could remove some zeros. Infact the resultant L should be a number rather a vector or matrix. Always R is a  N x 1 vector, but thats not the case here its multivariate situation now.

Comment: In this case L won't be a number. The first multiplication can be done without problems: 

L1=R'*P -> (173628x84)x(84x84) -> 173628x84

The problem would be the second one because the result will be that the size of L 173628x173628 (requiring a lot or RAM) and not a number as you expect

Comment: What If I do 

         for i = 1:size(R, 2)
               L(i,:) = RR(:,i)'*P * RR(:,i);
         end

This will give me a vector L of size 173628 x 1.